# Using structure as a value in map in C++

Tags: c++, struct, hashmap

I am working on a legacy code, there is a class A which has an enum member defined like this

```
class A
{
private:
 enum E{ kRemove, kDoNotRemove};
 static map<String, MapValue> s_Map; //this map I am trying to add
}
```

I am trying to add a map in this class which will have structure as a value something like this

```
 struct MapValue{
      E e; //this enum is defined in private section in the class
      String T;
      String F;
  } ;
```

What I am unable to understand where should I define this struct MapValue?

My understanding:

- If I add it inside the class Whenever I will create an object, a
  struct var will be allocated. This is not useful, as I am using this
  struct only as the value for the map. Also it is not the case that I
  need only one copy of this struct as I am using it as a value in the
  map.
- If I add it outside the class, it will not be a good design as the
  struct is only inside the class, so it should not be global. Also the
  struct has enum member which is defined as private in the class, so
  it is not accessible outside the class.

Please suggest.

Comment: "_If I add it inside the class Whenever I will create an object, a struct var will be allocated._" Why do you think so?

Comment: it would help if you show some code demonstrating the first issue, because there is some misunderstanding... or maybe you are already happy with the given answer

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius sorry my understanding is incorrect and I am thankful for the answer provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare the type inside the class, it's just like the enum declaration, you are not allocating a new instance. This will only happen when an object is created int he map.